# Cannot read property of undefined - cdkDropListData drag-drop Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I'm using the new Angular 7 Material CDK drag-drop feature to move item from a list to another and visually everything rocks when moving those but when changing item through lists I'm getting an error saying can't get a property (the list array) from undefined, even if I'm using the "item?.array" thing

in constructor:

```
this.userService.getUserById('some-user-id').subscribe(user => {
  this.user1 = user;
  console.log(user1.route.routePoints); // I see the array in log
});

this.userService.getUserById('some-other-user-id').subscribe(user => {
  this.user2 = user;
  console.log(user2.route.routePoints); // I see the array in log
});
```

Here I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'routePoints' of undefined" when dragging item from a list to another

```
<div cdkDropList #routeA="cdkDropList" cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" 
[cdkDropListData]="user1?.route?.routePoints"
class="list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event, false, user1)" 
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[queue, routeB]">
```

Here's the drag code:

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<RoutePoint[]>, fromQueue: boolean = false, user: User) {
  if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
    moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  } else {
    transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data, event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
  this.userService.updateUser(user);
}
```

Comment: Please, check that in the template, cdkDropListData points to a valid array (not undefined) in the moment of the dragging. It could be that some other functions reset the array to undefined (as it could happen in cdkDropListEnterPredicate handler). A empty array will be valid. Maybe you could start debugging with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as marcinolawski @ https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15948 mentioned, the reason is:

> The problem is that _DragRef.initialContainer == undefined. This is because _DragRef.initializeDragSequence() is called earlier than _DragRef.withDropContainer(). _initializeDragSequence() initializes the _initialContainer based on _dropContainer, _dropContainer is initialized by _withDropContainer() but because _initializeDragSequence() is called earlier than _withDropContainer() _initialContainer is set to undefined. More info: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-ref.ts

an ugly but working workaround for that is to trigger change detection on AfterViewChecked as follows (by lukaszgodula @ the same github above):

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
   this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

and of course inject ChangeDetectorRef to the component:

```
constructor(
   private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to initialize the `user1` array first

```
user: yourType = {};

this.userService.getUserById('some-user-id').subscribe(user => {
  this.user1 = user;
  console.log(user1.route.routePoints); // I see the array in log
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error cause my cdkDropListData element was not immediate parent of cdkdrag element, there was tab element in between causing issue. its ng version 7.x